Reading .gdx files without GAMS software
How can I read data from a .gdx file without having GAMS software installed on my computer? I have Jupyter Notebook and Python, and would like to load that data into a Python script.
I've tried to use the libraries gdxpds and gamspy, but looks like they ask for a GAMS software installed to work.

The easiest is to download and install GAMS and export the GDX file to a format you can read (e.g. CSV files).
If you don't want to do that, you can build the GDX API from https://github.com/GAMS-dev/gdx.

In addition to the answer of Erwin, you can also install GAMS Python API with pip install gamsapi and load your gdx as follows:
import gams.transfer as gt
m = gt.Container('<path_to_your_gdx_file>')

This would populate the GTP container with the symbols in the gdx file. If you want to inspect the data of a particular symbol, you can do the following:
print(m['<symbol_name>'].records)

All records are stored in Python as Pandas DataFrames.
If you also want to do your modelling in Python, then you can use GAMSPy.
